# Problem with some hidden == operand when erasing shared_ptr from a vector

Tags: c++, c++20

I wrote this AddressBook program in C++ as an exercise, and everything works fine except the `removeContact` method.
The compiler (MSVC) reports an issue related, I think, to some sort of incompatible right operand with a `==` operator.
Here's the compiler output:

```
error C2679: binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::shared_ptr<Contact>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  
note: could be 'bool std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>::operator ==(const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>> &) noexcept const' [synthesized expression 'y == x']  
   with  
        [  
            _Ty=Database::ContactPtr  
        ]  
note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::shared_ptr<Contact>, const _Ty)'  
 with  
        [        
 _Ty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Database::ContactPtr>>>  
        ]  
note: see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::remove<std::shared_ptr<Contact>*,_Uty>(_FwdIt,const _FwdIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled  
        with  
        [  
            _FwdIt=std::shared_ptr<Contact> *,  
_Uty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Database::ContactPtr>>>,
            _Ty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Database::ContactPtr>>>  
        ]  
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int  std::_Erase_remove<std::vector<Database::ContactPtr,std::allocator<Database::ContactPtr>>,_Uty>(_Container &,const _Uty &)' being compiled  
        with  
        [  
_Uty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Database::ContactPtr>>>,  
            _Container=std::vector<Database::ContactPtr,std::allocator<Database::ContactPtr>>  
        ]  
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int  std::erase<Database::ContactPtr,std::allocator<Database::ContactPtr>,std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>>(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,const _Uty &)' being compiled  
        with  
        [  
            _Ty=Database::ContactPtr,  
_Uty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Database::ContactPtr>>>
```

I don't know if the issue is something really simple, but this report is cryptic.
Here's the code:

```
#include "Database.h"
#include "ContactNotFoundException.h"

void Database::addContact(const Contact &contact) {
    contacts.push_back(std::make_shared<Contact>(contact));
}

void Database::removeContact(const Contact &contact) {
    removeContact(findContact(contact.getName()));
}

void Database::removeContact(std::string_view name) {
    removeContact(findContact(name));
}

void Database::removeContact(const size_t index) {
    auto iterator{contacts.begin()};
    iterator += static_cast<int>(contacts.size() - index);
    std::erase(contacts, iterator);
}

size_t Database::findContact(std::string_view name) const {
    // TODO: algorithm
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contacts.size(); ++i) {
        if (contacts.at(i)->getName() == name)
            return i;
    }
    throw ContactNotFoundException();
}

Database::ContactPtr Database::getContact(std::string_view name) const {
    return contacts.at(findContact(name));
}

void Database::listContacts() const {
    for (const auto& contactPtr : contacts) {
        std::cout << contactPtr->getName() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I also have to clarify that I put the compiler output in a code block because StackOverflow wouldn't let me post the answer, as it detects it as code.

Comment: Not related to your error, but another problem. `findContact()` returns an index. When `removeContact()` gets an iterator from `begin()` and increments it, why is it subtracting that index from the `size()` instead of using the index as-is? For example, say `findContact()` returns index 1 for the 2nd element in a 10 element list. You would be erasing the 10th element, not the 2nd element. If `findContact()` returned index 0 for the 1st element, you would actually erase out of bounds. So, `iterator += static_cast<int>(contacts.size() - index);` should be simply `iterator += index;` instead.

Comment: Yes, I know. I solved this bug on my own about five minutes ago, but thank you anyway!

Comment: Please see [ask], in particular that we expect a [mcve]. Separately, `auto iterator{contacts.begin()}; iterator += static_cast<int>(contacts.size() - index);` is a very tedious way of writing `auto iterator = contacts.begin() + index;` (which itself was hard to determine since nowhere in the question is `contacts` defined and I instead had to parse the error message).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) takes a value which is searched in your container and then removed, not an iterator.

Therefore trying to pass an iterator there triggers an error because `std::erase` is trying to compare your container elements with this iterator, but iterators and elements are normally not comparable.

To erase an element you already have an iterator for, you need [`contacts.erase(iterator)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, I read the cpp reference of vector::erase but wrote the std version, that's why I was trying to use the iterator.